# Multiple tags in list.map() syntax for React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
return (
    </React.Fragment>
        ...
        <div className="col-md-6">
            {firstHalfy1.map(month => (<Field key={month.id} {...month}/>))}
        </div>        
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

I want to add another tag/functional component after the  component, but the syntax doesn't seem to work. Ideally I want something like:

```
{firstHalfy1.map(month => (<Field/><Component2/>))}
```

is this syntax possible as I am trying to render a button (Component2) after every input (Field)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{firstHalfy1.map(month => (<div key={your key}><Field/><Component2/></div>))}
```

You need a wrapper for those components, such as a `div` or `React.Fragment`. Plus you need a key for each month.

Answer (score 1):

You can use from fragment like this:
    <>...  
This empty tag is also fragment

```
{firstHalfy1.map(month => (
     <React.Fragment key={month.id}>
        <Field {...month}/> 
        <Component2/>
    </React.Fragment>
))}
```

Comment: This is not exactly correct, you can't have the key in one of the components. The key should be at the top-level component.